# How to set the height of an ipywidgets.Text?

Tags: python, widget, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I am trying:

```py
from ipywidgets import Text, Layout
Text('test', layout=Layout(height='15px'))
```

but, it doesn't shrink the height of the Text widget frame. Instead, it just shows the frame cropped. See here:

[image]

How to properly get a Text widget with a specified frame height?